# UN Comtrade Database: Trade value when no quantity reported

Tags: trade, un

I am working on a project where I need the trade data for a specific type of generator and I'm using the UN Comtrade database. Some countries report no quantity (quantity code 1) but do report a positive trade value. I am thinking that they do import this type of generator but do not provide the quantity but I haven't found any documentation about this happening so I am not positive.

Does anyone know why there may be trade values that do not reflect the number of reported units?

Additionally, I'm confused by the actual reporting of trade values. [This](https://comtrade.un.org/data/MethodologyGuideforComtradePlus.pdf) document (page 6) implies that CIF trade values and FOB values could be reported, depending on what the country does. However, I don't see any field that would indicate another trade value or if an import value is CIF or FOB. Could anyone shed some light on this?

[image: Here's and example of the data I'm seeing]